# comparing 2 arrays with recursion (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, compare

i have to get scan the size, and 2 arrays, and compare them with recursion return 1 if they are the same, else return 0.

for example if i've got: size=5, arr1= 1 2 3 4 5, arr2= 2 1 3 4 5 so its good and 1 should be returned, when i run the program with the size of 2, and insert "1,2" for first array and "3,4" for second array the program return 0. which is good, but if enter "1,2" "1,2" i'm getting an error.

```
 int RecSearch(int* arr1,int* arr2,int n)
{
int i=0,j=0;
for(i=j;j<n;j++)
    if(arr1[i]==arr2[j])
      {
        swap(&arr2[i],&arr2[j]);
        RecSearch(arr1-1,arr2-1,n);
      }
      if (arr1==arr2) return 1;
      else return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your problem is? Also, you should define clearer what means "the same" because [1,2,3,4,5] and [2,1,3,4,5] definitely are not the same array.

Comment: 'comparing 2 arrays with recursion'........why?

Comment: i have to use recursion and only 1 for loop.

Comment: what do you mean by "comparing"? Why are you using a `swap()` method?

Comment: because i was told that i have to take the first  number of the first array (arr1[i]) and compare it with all the numbers in arr2. if it finds the same number,  bring the number from arr2 to the beginning and use recursion, and repeat until both arrays are empty. if they are empty they are the same.

Comment: Why on earth are you swapping two identical values?

Comment: And it should be the most expensive algorithm to compare two arrays

Comment: And why do you need recursion? This is very simple with regular loops.

Comment: @javier_el_bene yes, I'm far from convinced that this question is useful to future users/visitors :(

Comment: @ThingyWotsit im studying C in university, and they asked to do it in recurisve way.

Comment: @IliaNaleva yes, all the skilled and experienced engineers here guessed that.  The thing is, it's quite possibly the worst possible way of comparing two arrays and so it's of negative help to future users/visitors:(

Comment: `RecSearch(arr1-1,arr2-1,n);` is called, yet its return value is not used.  So no matter what that recursive call does, it does not reflect on the final returned value - certainly a suspect algorithm

Answer (score 0):

```
int recursion(int * arr1, int * arr2, int size, int curr)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr1[i] == arr2[curr])
        {
            curr++;

            if (curr == size)
                return 1;

            return recursion(arr1,arr2,size,curr);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The initial call of this function is:

```
int arr1[5] = {0,1,2,5,4};
int arr2[5] = {2,3,2,0,1};

int result = recursion(arr1, arr2, 5, 0);
```